# Como puedo colocar un LoadPage en Selenium de forma global

Tags: java, selenium

Buen día, 
estoy automatizando un aplicativo web (Con JAVA-Selenium), dado a que tengo que esperar entre paginas, estoy usando el Thread.sleep pero se me hace una mala practica porque lo estoy metiendo entre cada linea de codigo, quisiera saber si existe una extensión o una linea de codigo que permita definir de manera global en el proyecto que cada linea de codigo se **ejecute inmediatamente se haya cargado la pagina totalmente**

Agradezco ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar utilizar los Thread.sleep en Selenium cuentas con dos tipos de esperas, **implícitas** y **explicitas**.

Las esperas **implícitas** es el tiempo que va a esperar *WebDriver* para encontrar un elemento que no esta disponible y se definen cuando se crea el *WebDriver*.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Las esperas **explicitas** es el tiempo que se espera hasta que se cumpla una **condición** para buscar un elemento.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
```

.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));

Existen muchos tipos de **condiciones** como por ejemplo que un elemento este visible, sea clickable, que su valor sea X, etc etc.

Aquí tienes un link con la documentación de Selenium donde explican mas detalladamente las esperas y los tipos de esperas:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Y aquí la documentación de Selenium con todos los tipos de condiciones:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html